# How to get params of an object for edit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

I'm having an issue with a DateTime attribue. The question is that I've created a modal bootstrap to edit my events in Fullcalendar. When I click on the events it comes up a modal that contains a form to edit the event. The problem is that I don't know how to get the params of the event I've clicked on. I show you the form, the controller, the view and the javascript.

javascript code (Fullcalendar) In the eventClick I pass the url of that control.

```
function drawControl(controls) {
        console.log(controls[0])

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            contentHeight: 500,
            scrollTime: '24:00:00',
            minTime: '01:00:00',
            maxTime: '24:00:00',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header:{left:"prev,next,today",
            center:"title",
            right:"month, agendaWeek, agendaDay"},



            events: allControls(controls),

            eventRender: function(event, element) {

                var bloodLevel=event.title

                if(bloodLevel >= 180) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
                else if(bloodLevel < 70) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
                $('#modalDate').html(calEvent.start);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href',"/users/:user_id/controls/calEvent.id/edit");
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
            } //....
```

_form_edit.erb In the form_edit I pass as default @control_day, which is the DateTime of that event

```
<div class="">
<%= form_for [@user, @control], :html => {:class => ''} do |f| %>
    <p class="new_control_text">Edit Control</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.label :level, class: "sr-only", for: "exampleInputEmail2" %>

          <%= f.number_field :level, class: "form-control", id: "exampleInputEmail2", placeholder: "Enter level" %>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group container">
        <div class="row datetimeselect">
            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>

                        <%= f.text_field :day, default: @control_day, :class => 'form-control' %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>

    <div class="select_period">
       <%= f.select :period, options_for_select([['pre-breakfast'], ['post-breakfast'],['pre-lunch'],['post-lunch'],['afternoon'],['pre-dinner'],['post-dinner']]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>      

      <%= f.submit "Save", type:"submit", class: "btn btn-default button-save" %>

<% end %>
</div>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
          <%= render 'form_edit' %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"><a id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controlsController.rb Hear I convert the datetime to the DateTimepicker format

```
def edit
    @user = current_user
    @control = Control.find(params[:id])
    @control_day = @control.day.strftime('%m','%d','%Y','%I','%M','%p')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the documents and looked at what is in the Event Object?
for example: calEvent.start is a moment object, so setting it to the HTML on your modal likely isn't what you want to do with it.

checkout the momentjs documentation for how to use the calEvent.start.format() or other features.